# is there any way to catch the exception (outside) thrown by async callback in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

is there any way to catch the exception (outside) thrown by async callback in nodejs?

I am trying to throw an exception from `on('end')` callback of Node.js Transform stream. I have gone through the article https://bytearcher.com/articles/why-asynchronous-exceptions-are-uncatchable/ and it says it is not possible.

I am posting here to confirm the same.

Comment: Post your code here please and explain your usecase.

Comment: We can show you how to solve your problem, but only if your post your actual code.  There is no generic answer to what you're asking - the only answer involves your specific code.  You are mixing an object that uses events with the promise architecture and that requires some manual coding with promises.  Show the actual code and we can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am posting here to confirm the same.

The article is correct. Do not `throw` exceptions from asynchronous callbacks, they'll crash your server.

Use callbacks or promises for asynchronous code.